# arthas ognl map return null

Tags: dictionary, ognl

this is a map return

```
@LinkedHashMap[
    @String[6]:@ChapterInfo[com.elex.billion.icefire.game.biz.model.mission.chapterMission.ChapterInfo@50d60a4a],
    @String[7]:@ChapterInfo[com.elex.billion.icefire.game.biz.model.mission.chapterMission.ChapterInfo@4a5f4b44],
    @String[8]:@ChapterInfo[com.elex.billion.icefire.game.biz.model.mission.chapterMission.ChapterInfo@2d8b8b8e],
    @String[9]:@ChapterInfo[com.elex.billion.icefire.game.biz.model.mission.chapterMission.ChapterInfo@5990bae5],
    @String[10]:@ChapterInfo[com.elex.billion.icefire.game.biz.model.mission.chapterMission.ChapterInfo@39747fc7],
    @String[11]:@ChapterInfo[com.elex.billion.icefire.game.biz.model.mission.chapterMission.ChapterInfo@94106c6],
]
```

but i use 'get(6)' return null. 'get(@String[6])' is a Exception.

this is my line.

```
ognl @com.elex.billion.icefire.game.Application@getBean(@com.elex.billion.icefire.game.biz.manager.MissionManager@class).getPlayerChapterMission(100000000000031L).getChapterId2Info().get(6)
```

How can i get value with a key? thanks.

Comment: The key type of your map is `string` type, but the `integer` type is used in your ongl. In the HashMap of Java, the hash calculation method has changed, resulting in a null value

Answer (score 0):

```
ognl @com.elex.billion.icefire.game.Application@getBean(@com.elex.billion.icefire.game.biz.manager.MissionManager@class).getPlayerChapterMission(100000000000031L).getChapterId2Info().get(\"6\")
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] and explain what you did in your answer?

Comment: [ongl language](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-ognl/language-guide.html)。HTH！